# Match Two Columns with Different Factor Levels

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a variable emotion and a variable response. The emotion variable has 7 levels. The response variable has the same 7 levels, and the additional level "other". I want to create a new variable that codes 1 if emotion and response match, and 0 if they don´t match.
I tried the following code based on another stack overflow thread:

```
df$correct <- sapply(df$Emotion, function(x) {
  j <- which(df$Response == x) 
  ifelse(length(j) > 0, 1, 0) 
})
```

I get the error message that the number of levels of the factors are different (which is true). Does anyone know how to resolve that?

Comment: Can you add some sample data using `dput` and show expected output for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running your code, add the level `"other"` to `df$Emotion`:

`levels(df$Emotion) <- c(levels(df$Emotion), "other")`

Morevoer, I would substitute your code with the following line:

`df$correct <- ifelse(df$Emotion == df$Response, 1, 0)`

Your code does not seem to perform correctly the action that you need to perform.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. What additional steps are needed to address the OP's issue and "to create a new variable that codes 1 if emotion and response match, and 0 if they don´t match"?

Comment: Actually, the suggestion by Carlo works! Thank you!